# SQL Oracle turning decimal number into string

Tags: sql, oracle, format

I have rather simple question: I have a column with interest rates stored as decimals (e.g. 0,400 , 0,03 etc) and I'd like to turn them into %. I tried following code:

```
select xy, interest_rate*100 ||'%' as intr_prc
from xyz
```

but when the decimal is like 0,001 instead of getting 0,2% I get ,2% which looks pretty awful since its hardly noticeable that there is a ',' before the number.

I use pl/sql developer.

Thanks!

Problem is that when I try to add the '%' symbol the number turns into char in throughout the process decimals starting with 0 lose that number (0,1 -> ,1%) etc

Comment: Can you fix it in the presentation layer instead?

Comment: @jarlh sadly I can't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select xy, to_char(interest_rate*100,'990.00') ||'%' as intr_prc
from xyz
```

Whenever conversions are to take place, use the conversion functions to_char or to_number or to_date, depending on what you need so that you avoid implicit conversions. Imnplicit conversions quite frequently lead to errors or undesired results.